# problem with btrfs tools

Tags: partitioning, backup

I've installed btrf-tools and I would like to shrink 5gb off my primary partition for use as a temporary snapshot for a `dd` backup.  But first things first ...

```
me@my:~$ btrfs fi show
failed to open /dev/sda: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sda1: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdb: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdb1: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdb2: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdb5: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdc: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/sdc1: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/dm-0: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/dm-1: Permission denied
Btrfs v0.20-rc1
me@my:~$ sudo btrfs fi show
Btrfs v0.20-rc1
me@my:~$ sudo btrfs fi df /dev/sdb1
ERROR: couldn't get space info on '/dev/sdb1' - Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

These are not the outputs I expect.  You see that when I am not root, I get permissions errors.  When I am root, I get nothing.  (I assume "Btrfs v0.20-rc1" is not a device/mount, but just a traditional banner (footer?).)

What's going on?

Thanks!

Here's what GParted shows

[image]

@Grumbel brings up a good point!  Maybe I don't have btrfs at all.  I am really certain that I selected it during installation because it seemed to be the newfangled thing over ext4.  Only thing I can think is that also checking LVM overrode the filesystem choice??

`cat /etc/fstab` says

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

So I guess I'm not on what I thought I was on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btrfs fi show` scans all your devices to find if any contains a btrfs, so error messages when running it as users are to be expected, as you don't have access rights. If you run as root and don't have any btrfs then you get the output you got. If you do have a btrfs and `btrfs fi show` can't find it, there might be something wrong.

`btrfs fi df` simply needs to be run on the mountpoint, not the block device.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm pretty sure I selected Btrfs on install.  What's my mountpoint in this case?

Comment: I added some detail - does that all add up to you?  I'm on ext4 after all, case closed?

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are running ext4. If you are adventurous you can shrink it and make a btrfs in the empty space with `resize2fs` and `lvreduce`.